# Debug "Clear All" option in VS2010 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and because of the amount of debug output I'm producing, and the difficulty of finding the beginning of the output for a new run, I have been manually using the Debug "Clear All" action (from the mouse right-click popup menu on the Debug output window).  Plus I have to put some kind of break or dialog box in the beginning, just so I have a chance to do this before the debug output gets going.

Well after a couple of thousand times, this is getting very, very old (seriously, because its come up in almost every programming project I've done in the last five years).  But I cannot seem to find any option or simple Debug.{method} to do this automatically for me.

This has been bugging me forever, and though its a simple question, I have never found an easy answer (short of writing my own listener) in any version of the .net VS IDE's.

Anyone know how to do this or have any ideas?  thnx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the middle of the output window and turn off all but Program Output

[image]

Comment: I *want* the debug output.  I just don't want the output from the previous run.

Comment: In the example displayed, I am ONLY getting debug output.  Every time I run it, it starts with a blank output window.  At least it does on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in cases like this is to use [Debug View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) but to see the debug output in Debug view you need to detach the process from you visual studio debugger. You can do that through the Debug->Processes window.

What debug view provides is extra highlighting and coloring of different kind of debug output so that the relevant things are easily recognizable. Furthermore, you can stop receiving debug output by simply hitting a key on its toolbar.

I know that this might not answer your question but this at least gives you an option to do it otherwise.